# Type level arithmetic using kindsignatures and typeoperators?

Tags: haskell

I was messing around with datakinds in ghc 7.6 and it didn't quite work the way I thought it should.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, TypeOperators #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

data Array (i :: Nat) a = Array {
  num :: Int,
  elems :: [a]
} deriving (Eq, Show)

arr10 :: Array 10 Int
arr10 = arrn 10

arr20 :: Array 20 Int
arr20 = arrn 20

arrn :: Int -> Array a Int
arrn n = Array n (replicate n 0)

arrconcat :: Array a e -> Array b e -> Array (a+b) e
arrconcat (Array a as) (Array b bs) = Array (a+b) (as ++ bs)
```

in ghci:

```
*Main> arr10 
Array {num = 10, elems = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}

*Main> arr10 == arr10
True

*Main> arr20
Array {num = 20, elems = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}

*Main> arr10 `arrconcat` arr20
Array {num = 30, elems = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}

*Main> :t arr10 `arrconcat` arr20
arr10 `arrconcat` arr20 :: Array (10 + 20) Int

*Main> :t arr10 `arrconcat` arr10 == arr20
<interactive>:1:1:
    Couldn't match type `10 + 10' with `20'
    Expected type: Array 20 Int
      Actual type: Array (10 + 10) Int
    In the first argument of `(==)', namely `arr10 `arrconcat` arr10'
    In the expression: arr10 `arrconcat` arr10 == arr20
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do with this sort of type level numeric or is it planned to work eventually?

Comment: They're hoping to get some version of the type-nats solver in for GHC 7.8... the work is going on here https://github.com/ghc/ghc/tree/type-nats-simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type families and data kinds are actually powerful enough to do this if you define type-level Peano numbers like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

data Array (i :: Nat) a = Array {
  num :: Int,
  elems :: [a]
} deriving (Eq, Show)

arrn :: Int -> Array a Int
arrn n = Array n (replicate n 0)

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

type family Add (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat
type instance Add Zero m = m
type instance Add (Succ n) m = Succ (Add n m)

type Ten = Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))))))))
type Twenty = Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))))))))))))))))))

arr10 :: Array Ten Int
arr10 = arrn 10

arr20 :: Array Twenty Int
arr20 = arrn 20

arrconcat :: Array a e -> Array b e -> Array (Add a b) e
arrconcat (Array a as) (Array b bs) = Array (a+b) (as ++ bs)
```

This works as you'd expect:

```
*Main> :t arr10 `arrconcat` arr10 == arr20
arr10 `arrconcat` arr10 == arr20 :: Bool
*Main> arr10 `arrconcat` arr10 == arr20
True
```

Unfortunately the `TypeLits` are a bit undercooked at the moment. But as Nathan Howell already commented, they are being worked on and should be much better in GHC 7.8. It's going to be great!

Comment: Yeah I've done stuff similar to this.  It is good to know that there is some fun stuff in this area on the way.  I can think of a more than a few ways to use that already.