# Lists of fixed length and type literals

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference

I'm trying to define a type for lists of fixed length in Haskell. When I use the standard way to encode natural numbers as types in unary, everything works fine. However, when I try to build everything on GHC's type literals, I run into tons of problems.

My first shot at the desired list type was

```
data List (n :: Nat) a where
  Nil :: List 0 a
  (:>) :: a -> List n a -> List (n+1) a
```

which unfortunately didn't allow for writing a zip function with type

```
zip :: List n a -> List n b -> List n (a,b)
```

I could solve this problem by subtracting 1 from the type variable `n` in the type of `(:>)`:

```
data List (n :: Nat) a where
  Nil :: List 0 a
  (:>) :: a -> List (n-1) a -> List n a -- subtracted 1 from both n's
```

Next, I tried to define an append function:

```
append :: List n1 a -> List n2 a -> List (n1 + n2) a
append Nil       ys = ys
append (x :> xs) ys = x :> (append xs ys)
```

Unfortunately, GHC tells me

```
Couldn't match type ‘(n1 + n2) - 1’ with ‘(n1 - 1) + n2’
```

Adding the constraint `((n1 + n2) - 1) ~ ((n1 - 1) + n2)` to the signature doesn't solve the problems since GHC complains

```
Could not deduce ((((n1 - 1) - 1) + n2) ~ (((n1 + n2) - 1) - 1))
from the context (((n1 + n2) - 1) ~ ((n1 - 1) + n2))
```

Now, I'm obviously caught in some kind of infinite loop.

So, I'd like to know if it is possible to define a type for lists of fixed length using type literals at all. Did I perhaps even oversee a library for precisely this purpose? Basically, the only requirement is that I want to write something like `List 3 a` instead of `List (S (S (S Z))) a`.

Comment: You can find some discussion about the issues related to type-level vector lengths in the Hasochism paper: https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf

Comment: "Hasochism" sounds really tempting. I'll give the paper a try nevertheless. Thank you.

Comment: It's probably easier to make a newtype wrapper around a normal list with a `Nat` attached, similar to how `Linear.V` does it. You can define a few primitives in one module and hide the constructor to make everything safe.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not really an answer.

Using https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise-0.2 , this

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data List (n :: Nat) a where
  Nil :: List 0 a
  (:>) :: a -> List n a -> List (n+1) a

append :: List n1 a -> List n2 a -> List (n1 + n2) a
append Nil       ys = ys
append (x :> xs) ys = x :> (append xs ys)
```

... compiles, so obviously it's correct.

[image: ???]

Comment: I didn't know about plugins for the type checker at all, but that works really nicely. Thank you.

Comment: How would I implement a function `fill :: a -> List n a` that fills a `List` with a constant value? Is there maybe some kind of pattern matching to switch between these two cases: `fill x = Nil; fill x = x :> fill x`

Answer (score 7):

Type level number literals don't yet have a structure on which we can do induction, and the built-in constraint solver can only figure out the simplest cases. Currently it's better to stick with Peano naturals.

However, we can still use the literals as syntactic sugar.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  UndecidableInstances,
  DataKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies #-}

import qualified GHC.TypeLits as Lit

data Nat = Z | S Nat

type family Lit n where
    Lit 0 = Z
    Lit n = S (Lit (n Lit.- 1))
```

Now you can write `List (Lit 3) a` instead of `List (S (S (S Z))) a`.

Comment: I had a similar idea too, but using `UndecidableInstances` always scares me a bit. Using another type synonym I could even arrive at `List 3 a` then.

Comment: Here the type family obviously terminates, so there's zero issue with `UndecidableInstances`. Even in the general case, I don't find it really scary. If we accidentally write divergent type-level code, we almost always get a context depth limit error. It's very rare that we can actually get GHC loop, and we can easily rectify that problem with a Ctr-c.