# Must I cast Nat-kinds every time?

Tags: haskell, gadt, data-kinds

I tried to simulate a quantum computer. Here is the datatype representing qubits:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Equality
import GHC.TypeNats

import Data.Group.Cyclic

data QBits :: Nat -> * where
    N :: QBits 0
    C :: KnownNat n => Bool -> QBits n -> QBits (n+1)
    S :: KnownNat n => Cyclic 4 -> QBits n -> QBits n -> QBits (n+1)
```

`N` represents zero qubits.

`C`, standing for "classical", assigns the first qubit a boolean value, and specifies the rest.

`S`, standing for "superposed", states that the first qubit is in superposition, and specifies the rest for each possibility in which the first qubit will fall when measured. It also specifies the phase difference, which is a value in `Cyclic 4`, which is the ring Z/4Z and has `Num` instance.

For `instance Eq (QBits n)`, I have a workaround so I won't mess with `Nat`:

```
(=?=) :: QBits m -> QBits n -> Bool
N =?= N = True
C b x =?= C c y = b == c && x =?= y
S p x y =?= S q u v = p == q && x =?= u && y =?= v
_ =?= _ = False

instance Eq (QBits n) where
    (==) = (=?=)
```

Then I implemented `swapGate`, which swaps first two qubits:

```
castNat :: forall f m n. (KnownNat m, KnownNat n) => f m -> Maybe (f n)
castNat x = do
    refl <- sameNat (Proxy :: Proxy m) (Proxy :: Proxy n)
    return (castWith (apply Refl refl) x)

swapGate :: KnownNat n => QBits n -> QBits n
swapGate (C b (C c x)) = C c (C b x)
swapGate (C b (S p x y)) = S p (C b x) (C b y)
swapGate (S r (C False x) (C False y)) = let
    Just y' = castNat y
    in C False (S r x y')
swapGate (S r (C False x) (S q u v)) = let
    Just u' = castNat u
    in S (r+q) (S r x u') (C True v)
swapGate (S r (C True y) (C False u)) = S (-r) (C True u) (C False y)
swapGate (S r (C True y) (C True v)) = let
    Just v' = castNat v
    in C True (S r y v')
swapGate (S r (C True y) (S q u v)) = let
    Just v' = castNat v
    in S (-r) (C True u) (S (r+q) y v')
swapGate (S r (S p x y) (C False u)) = let
    Just u' = castNat u
    in S p (S r x u') (C False y)
swapGate (S r (S p x y) (C True v)) = let
    Just v' = castNat v
    in S p (C False x) (S (p-r) y v')
swapGate (S r (S p x y) (S q u v)) = let
    Just u' = castNat u
    Just v' = castNat v
    in S p (S r x u') (S (q-p+r) y v')
swapGate z = z
```

The fact I must cast `Nat`s is just too annoying. Is `castNat` truly mandatory?

Comment: GHC cannot into math. Either use Peano naturals `data Nat = Z | S Nat` (which might automatically get you all of your equalities here) or use a compiler plugin that can make GHC simplify some of the math (e.g. equation 3 appears to fail because GHC doesn't know that `(m + 1) ~ (n + 1)` means `m ~ n`?).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lists of fixed length and type literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823345/lists-of-fixed-length-and-type-literals)

Comment: @LambdaFairy Only if that's the only solution.

Comment: @DannyuNDos It's sort of the intended solution: `Nat` exists mostly for the literal syntax; you're supposed to attach GHC to something else to handle the actual logic. I'm tired so no answer, but I encourage you to try the Peano naturals (here, I'll give you `type family N (n :: GHC.TypeNats.Nat) :: Nat where { N 0 = Z; N n = S (N (n GHC.TypeNats.- 1)) }`, which makes the their syntax nicer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, to fix the syntactic abomination, you could write:

```
c :: forall f m n. (KnownNat m, KnownNat n) => f m -> f n
c = fromJust . castNat
```

and then:

```
swapGate :: KnownNat n => QBits n -> QBits n
swapGate (C b (C c x)) = C c (C b x)
swapGate (C b (S p x y)) = S p (C b x) (C b y)
swapGate (S r (C False x) (C False y)) = C False (S r x (c y))
swapGate (S r (C False x) (S q u v)) = S (r+q) (S r x (c u)) (C True v)
... etc. ...
```

As explained in the comments, the underlying "problem" is that GHC's built-in inference for type-level naturals is very limited.  Operators will work on concrete types and handle a few special abstract cases, like `0 + m ~ m`, but GHC can't make other, even extremely simply inference, like `m + 1 - 1 ~ m` or "`m + 1 ~ n + 1` implies `m ~ n`".

Your choices are to rewrite using an algebraic `Nat` type (e.g., Peano naturals) or use a solver plugin.

For this problem, Peano naturals are an (erm...) natural fit, since all your manipulations of type level naturals involve incrementing or decrementing them.  After replacing `Nat` and the `+` type operator with:

```
data Nat = ZZ | SS Nat
type family m + n where
  ZZ + n = n
  SS m + n = m + SS n
```

and adjusting the `QBits` definition:

```
data QBits :: Nat -> * where
    N :: QBits ZZ
    C :: Bool -> QBits n -> QBits (SS n)
    S :: Cyclic4 -> QBits n -> QBits n -> QBits (SS n)
```

the castless definition typechecks fine:

```
swapGate :: QBits n -> QBits n
swapGate (C b (C c x)) = C c (C b x)
swapGate (C b (S p x y)) = S p (C b x) (C b y)
swapGate (S r (C False x) (C False y)) = C False (S r x y)
swapGate (S r (C False x) (S q u v)) = S (r+q) (S r x u) (C True v)
swapGate (S r (C True y) (C False u)) = S (-r) (C True u) (C False y)
swapGate (S r (C True y) (C True v)) = C True (S r y v)
swapGate (S r (C True y) (S q u v)) = S (-r) (C True u) (S (r+q) y v)
swapGate (S r (S p x y) (C False u)) = S p (S r x u) (C False y)
swapGate (S r (S p x y) (C True v)) = S p (C False x) (S (p-r) y v)
swapGate (S r (S p x y) (S q u v)) = S p (S r x u) (S (q-p+r) y v)
swapGate z = z
```

Alternatively, you can use a solver plugin.  After installing `ghc-typelits-natnormalise` and adding:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise #-}
```

to the top of your code, I can get rid of all the casts, and -- again -- it typechecks fine.

By the way, *either* of these solutions also allow you to drop the `KnownNat` constraints from the code, too.  If performance is a consideration, that may be a win, since you won't have to carry all these dictionaries around.